# I want to copy data from multiple .xml to a current excel

Tags: xml, excel, copy, repeat

I have a problem, I am new to vba programming and i am currently in a dilema.

I have a folder with 20-50 xml files containing test results. I want to create a macro to select the folder, open each .xml file and copy a very specific value(s). For example in column Z i have @NAMERecord and in column AA i have the data itself. Each .xml file has one or more data and i want to copy each data from each xml to a new column in my base workbook.
Also i want the first column to have the name of the file which i succeded in doing.

For the record each .xml file when you open you have to choose "Open the file without applying a stylesheet" which is just an "ok" to press and after you have to select "As a read-only workbook" and press "Ok".

My code so far looks like this but i got the error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method" and it shows it is present

"        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True"

I have Word 2003.

Hope someone can help and thank you in advance.

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub FileNames()

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

Dim strFolder As String, ws As Worksheet, StrFile As String, r As Range, My_Range As Range
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
If .Show = -1 Then _
strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

If strFolder = "" Then MsgBox "No folder selected! Exiting sub...": Exit Sub

    folderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    Set ws = Sheets("RawData")

    ws.Range("A1") = Array("FileName")
    StrFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xml")
    If StrFile <> "" Then
        Do
        Set r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        r.Value = StrFile: r.Offset(0).Value = StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
        Loop Until StrFile = ""
End If


 Do While Filename <> ""
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)

        Filename = Dir
    Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'Copiaza

Sub @NAMEuri()

    Dim WrkBook As Workbook
    Dim StrFileName As String
    Dim FileLocnStr As String
    Dim rowcounter As Integer

    FileLocnStr = CurDir() 'ThisWorkbook.Path

    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir(FileLocnStr & "\*.xml")

    rowcounter = 2
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Call Operations(FileLocnStr & "\" & StrFile, rowcounter)
    StrFile = Dir
    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1

Loop

Sheets(1).Select
MsgBox "Action Complete"

End Sub

Private Sub Operations(StrFileName As String, rowcounter As Integer)

    Workbooks.Open (StrFileName)

    Call Edit(rowcounter)

    Workbooks.Open (StrFileName)

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Sub Edit(rowcounter As Integer)
Dim lngCalc As Integer

Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim loopcal As Long


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    lngCalc = .Calculation
 End With

     Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter


If Range("Z2") = "/Function/Devices/Device/@NAME/ExtendedData/Data/@Name" Then

    Range("X4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$EW$2197").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:= _
        "@NAMERecord"


    Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("AA3:AA3000").Select
    Selection.Copy
ElseIf Range("AA2") = "/Function/Devices/Device/@NAME/ExtendedData/Data/@Name" Then

    Range("X4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$EW$2197").AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:= _
        "@NAMERecord"


    Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("AB3:AB3000").Select
    Selection.Copy
End If


    Windows(2).Activate
    Sheets(2).Select
    Range("B" & rowcounter).Select

'index the variable to ensure the cell reference changes each time.
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If they are always the same files, you could use a loop that opens up the files based on name. What are your criteria for if you copy a cell? And if it meets criteria, what do you copy? Do you copy the cell, the cell next to it or both?

Comment: The criteria is "@Name Record" and i copy the file nest to it to the right of the cell.

Also it uses a lot of memory....for every file i open the excel takes 1MB of RAM memory. Do you know why?